# JSON Serialize API that can return string or int

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm building an application for someone, but because of some bad choices in the start the API now returns errorcodes in string OR in integer format. In the past I was albe to simple map the objects to the API, but because if this I can't any more. Now I have no idea how to solve this without breaking the code that's dependent on this model.

The model:

```
public class JsonPayloadResponse<T>
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public int error { get; set; }
    public T data { get; set; }
}
```

The old parsing way:

```
 private T ConvertJsonToObject<T>(string payload)
        {
            try
            {
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(payload);
            }
            catch
            {
                return default(T);
            }
        }
```

What is the best and clean way to solve this?

Comment: Is declaring `data` as a `string` an option? JSON.NET will automatically convert an `int` to a `string` for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a property of type dynamic. Json.net correctly deserializes that property based on the actual value.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to avoid Json.NET and instead rely on System.Runtime.Serialization.Json, so I'll give a quick example on how to read a twitter user profile

The Model:

```
[DataContract]
struct TwitterProfile
{
    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public String Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "profile_image_url")]
    public String Avatar { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "statuses_count")]
    public Int32 Tweets { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "followers_count")]
    public Int32 Followers { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "friends_count")]
    public Int32 Following { get; set; }
}
```

And the parsing:

```
DataContractJsonSerializer Json = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(TwitterProfile));
TwitterProfile TwProfile = (TwitterProfile)Json.ReadObject(/*your stream*/);
```

Comment: 1) Json.Net is much more better than DataContractJsonSerializer 2) Which part of the question does this post answer? Question is not about a generic json deserialization.

Comment: Not only perforance, it is a *swiss army knife* of json.

Comment: Well, I read the comparison but If I can get the job done in the .net framework I would rather not depend on a third party dll.

Comment: Even MS uses this *"third party dll."*  in MVC. Not built-in *DataContractJsonSerializer*, or *JavascriptSerializer*

Comment: It's now the de facto standard in Json serialization in .net. Soon the Microsoft implementation might become 3rd party ;)